# Match only the last instance of a regex that I only know partially

Tags: regex

I want to match just the last instance of a regular expression. For example in this string:

some text here *foo word bar* and *foo word foo word **foo word bar*** more text here

I am trying to only match the bolded portion. Here is what I have tried currently:

```
 /foo?.+?bar/gi
```

However, it is keeping all of the italicized portion. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex that matches closes `foo...bar` pair without allowing any `foo` or `bar` in the middle:

```bash
foo(?:(?!foo|bar).)+bar(?!.*foo.+bar)
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/n2Zr15/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `foo`: Match `foo`
- `(?:(?!foo|bar).)+`: Match 1+ of any character as long as it is not immediately followed by a `foo` or `bar`.
- `bar`: Match `bar`
- `(?!.*foo.+bar)`: Make sure we don't have any `foo..bar` match on RHS

---

If you are fine with getting your match in a capture group then consider this more efficient version of regex:

```bash
.*(foo(?:(?!foo|bar).)+bar)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/n2Zr15/2)